# OptimisticLockException while deleting a set of entities concurrently

Tags: java, hibernate, google-app-engine, concurrency, ehcache

I am trying to create a simple Servlet method to delete a set of objects by using Hibernate.

```
List<MyEntity> entities = dao.getEntities(...); // just a query that returns a collection of managed entities

for (MyEntity entity : entities)
  dao.remove(entity); // em.remove(..) nothing more
```

Everything works as expected but... if I use jMeter and query my fantastic Servlet 200 times in a period of a few seconds then I may receive exceptions like this one below.

I would not be happy to use "delete from MyEntity..." update query because I also use a second level cache.

Exception:

```
[INFO] Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:94)
[INFO]  at xxx.xxx.xxx.TransactionTemplate.invokeWithinTransation(TransactionTemplate.java:23)
[INFO]  ... 42 more
[INFO] Caused by: javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.wrapStaleStateException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1800)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1705)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:82)
[INFO]  ... 43 more
[INFO] Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:81)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:73)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:63)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3400)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3630)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:114)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
[INFO]  ... 43 more
```

Comment: Two threads try to remove entities simultaneously

Comment: that is obvious but how to solve this :)

Comment: Most wide spread way to catch OptimisticException, rollback transaction and start operation from beginning.

Comment: Or you can use pessimistic locking :)

Comment: What is there to solve?  It's working properly as it's meant to.  What is it you would like to happen when two people try to delete the same list of things at the same time?

Comment: because they try to delete already deleted objects why have I to receive an exception. I do not see any conflict here.

Comment: How can I force Hibernate to delete an object from cache and db even if its not there? Rollbacks are time consuming.

Comment: In the real world, should two threads be able to delete the same entity/row (you don't say if you're using Cloud SQL or Datastore)?  Is your transaction idempotent?  If so, should a retry not succeed? (I don't know JPA/Hibernate).

Comment: yes, this function could be idempotent and I can retry but... I am using transaction templates and the code will look bad in the end, also I would like to avoid any rollbacks

Comment: The question scope has evolved gradually to the point that it seems this isn't appropriate for a Q&A site like Stack Overflow, but is more of a discussion of trade-offs which can take place in the given situation. I've recommended closing due to this, or perhaps the question can be edited so that a decisive answer is possible?